# Kloosterman Sums and Lattice Hyperbolas

Tags: sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory, equidistribution

Part of this [blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/08/26/heath-browns-theorem-on-prime-twins-and-siegel-zeroes/) discussing the twin prime conjecture mentions a connection between three objects:

- $ \sum_{x \leq n \leq 2x} \tau\Big(n(n+2)\Big)  $ average over twin primes where $\tau(n) = (1 \ast 1)(n) = \sum_{d|n} 1$
- $\# \Big\{ (a,b) : ab = -2 \mod d\Big\} \subseteq (\mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z})^2$ by solving the equation $ab-cd=2$
- $\sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z}} e\Big( \frac{a_1 m + a_2 \overline{m}}{r} \Big)$ by Taking a Fourier transform

---

Item #1 is pretty clear.  It is often equal to $\tau(n)\tau(n+2)$

That article glosses over numerous points.
**How is #2 a statement about [equidistribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) over the hyperbola?**

How is #3 the Fourier transform of item #2?  What is the relation between $r$ and $d$?

---

Later on the blog proves the [Kloosterman bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kloosterman_sum), some weak version of the Weil bound.

$$\sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z}} e\Big( \frac{a_1 m + a_2 \overline{m}}{r} \Big) \ll r^{3/4 +o(1)}\mathrm{gcd}(a,b,r)$$

The article does a decent job of explaining that if we proove this bound the Kloosterman averages vanish (upon division by $r$).

---

## Empirical Data Related to Equidistribution of $ab +2 = 0$ mod $d$

#### $d = 1500$

[image]

#### $d = 1000$

[image]

Comment: A lot of this is understandable, but (to me) not the actual question(s) you wish addressed.

Comment: @GregMartin this is how I feel about the blog I am reading :-(